# Check if the Nth number of Fibonacci is NthFib or not - arithmetic error fail

Tags: function, math, prolog, fibonacci, arithmetic-expressions

Here is my predicate, which should check if the `N`<sup>th</sup> number of Fibonacci is `NthFib` or not.

I am getting arithmetic is not function error.

```
K - current iteration
N - Nth number
Tmp - previous Fibonacci number
Ans - current Fibonacci number
```

Fibonacci sequence: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, etc. (sum of two previous = current)

```
fib(N, NthFib) :-
    fib(1, N, 1, 0, NthFib).

fib(K, N, Ans, Tmp, NthFib) :-
    % true if Ans is NthFib, false otherwise
    ( K > N -> Ans is NthFib
    ; K =< N -> fib( K + 1, N, Ans + Tmp, Ans, NthFib)
    ).
```

Comment: are you missing the homework tag?

Comment: That is not a homework, but a self-education. Now you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, re-write your original code as

```
fib(N, NthFib) :- fib(1, N, 1, 0, NthFib).

fib(K, N, Ans, Tmp, NthFib) :- 
  K > N -> Ans = NthFib;       % use = instead of is here
  K =< N -> fib((K+1), N, (Ans+Tmp), Ans, NthFib).
```

Now,

```
?- fib(7,X).

X = 1+0+1+ (1+0)+ (1+0+1)+ (1+0+1+ (1+0))+ (1+0+1+ (1+0)+ (1+0+1))+ 
       (1+0+1+ (1+0)+ (1+0+1)+ (1+0+1+ (1+0))) 

Yes
?- fib(7,X), Z is X.

X = 1+0+1+ (1+0)+ (1+0+1)+ (1+0+1+ (1+0))+ (1+0+1+ (1+0)+ (1+0+1))+ 
       (1+0+1+ (1+0)+ (1+0+1)+ (1+0+1+ (1+0)))
Z = 21
```

See, in Prolog data is symbolic, and using `is` forces the arithmetic expression into an arithmetic value (*evaluates* the expression under assumption that it is a meaningful arithmetic expression).

To check whether 20 is 7-th Fibonacci number, we can use arithmetic comparison operator which evaluates its arguments,

```
?- fib(7,X), X =:= 20.

No
```

Which means that your code just needs to be rewritten as

```
fib(N, NthFib) :- fib(1, N, 1, 0, NthFib).

fib(K, N, Ans, Tmp, NthFib) :- 
  K > N -> NthFib is Ans ;       % exchange the order of operands
  K =< N -> fib((K+1), N, (Ans+Tmp), Ans, NthFib).
```

Now it works as you intended:

```
?- fib(7,21).

Yes
?- fib(7,20).

No
```

But it doesn't work efficiently, carrying all those long expressions around as symbolic data. We only need the numbers really, so just as you were shown in other answers, `is` is used to achieve that. Every symbolic sub-expression that you have, take it out of its enclosing expression, and name it, using `is` instead of `=`.

BTW 21 really is an 8-th member of the sequence. Correct your code.

Answer (score 1):

If `K` is unified with `1`, `K + 1` is unified with `1 + 1`, not `2`.

Comment: K =< N -> K1 is K+1, Ans1 is Ans+Tmp, fib(K1, N, Ans1, Ans, NthFib)

Answer (score -1):

I have rewrote an algorithm, it is more simple and efficient now:

```
fib(0, 0).
fib(1, 1).
fib(N, F) :-
    N > 0,
    X is N - 2,
    Y is N - 1,
    fib(X, A),
    fib(Y, B),
    F is A + B.
```

Comment: No, no, NO! "More efficient"? No, *your original code* was efficient - i.e. linear - this is the classic tree-recursive code which takes enormous amounts of time to calculate the n-th number, as it recalculates fib(X) as part of calculating fib(Y) - whereas your original code ***re-used*** it by explicitly maintaining the two last values.

Comment: Yup, it's an exponential complexity algorithm. Your computer won't return much things when `N` is greater than 30 or so. Your previous algorithm - even if poorly implemented - was much better. See Will Ness's answer (+1)!